# Running two different test scenarios at the same time on two different devices calabash android

Tags: android, automation, automated-tests, appium, calabash-android

I am having a scenario as follows:

1. User 'A' logs in and make some action
2. User 'B' logs in and try to perform the same action
3. The system should give validation error ...saying 'locked'

How can I perform this action i.e 2 different users should log in to 2 different devices and try to perform the action as described above

What will be the command for running test case on 2 devices ..for example for 1 device it is :
calabash-android run test.apk ADB_DEVICE_ARG=emulator-1112

Can I run the same scenario on two different devices? and 2 different scenarios on 2 different devices from Calabash?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You just need to have *2 terminal / cmd windows* open and assuming that the application and test server are installed on the emulated devices, you run the following:

*In window 1:*

```
calabash-android run path\to\your\apk features\[insert_feature_name].feature ADB_DEVICES_ARG="emulator-1112" TEST_SERVER_PORT=34777
```

*In window 2*, same thing, you just **change** the **emulator** and **server port**:

```
calabash-android run path\to\your\apk features\[insert_feature_name].feature ADB_DEVICES_ARG="emulator-1113" TEST_SERVER_PORT=34778
```

Commands assume that you are in the project folder. Hope it helps.